Kotlin Multiplatform PendingIntent Not Navigating Correctly When App is Closed
Question:
I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform app with Android-specific code for handling notifications and deep links. The app uses a NotificationService to receive push notifications, which should navigate users to specific research screens based on a researchPath provided in the notification data.
Problem:
When the app is running (either in the foreground or background), the PendingIntent in the notification navigates correctly to the targeted research screen. However, when the app is closed, tapping the notification opens the app to the home screen rather than navigating directly to the intended research page.
Code Context:

NotificationService.kt
This service handles incoming notifications, sets up the notification channel, builds the notification, and creates a PendingIntent based on the researchPath in the message data.
class NotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        Log.i(TAG, "onMessageReceived: Message Received")
        createNotice(message)
    }

    private fun createNotice(message: RemoteMessage) {
        val getChannel = if (message.from?.contains("/topics/") == true) {
            if (message.from?.extractTopic() == Topics.ResearchPosted.name)
                ResearchNotification().notificationChannelId
            else
                FacultyNotification().notificationChannelId
        } else
            MessageNotification().notificationChannelId

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getChannel)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(message.notification?.title ?: "")
            .setContentText(message.notification?.body ?: "").setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)

        val key = message.data["created"]?.toLong()?.convertToInt() ?: Random.nextInt()
        val researchPath = message.data["key"] ?: "no_research"
        val pendingIntent = providePendingIntentNotice(researchPath)
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        managerCompat.notify(key, builder.build())
    }

    private fun providePendingIntentNotice(path: String): PendingIntent? {
        val deepLinkIntent = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            DeepLink.OpenResearch(researchPath = path).route.toUri(),
            this,
            MainActivity::class.java
        )
        val deepLinkPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
            addNextIntentWithParentStack(deepLinkIntent)
            getPendingIntent(0, getPendingIntentFlag())
        }
        return deepLinkPendingIntent
    }

    private fun getPendingIntentFlag() =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

    private fun String.extractTopic() = this.replace("/topics/", "")
}


MainScreenGraph.kt
This code defines the navigation graph and configures deep linking to handle the researchPath parameter.
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainScreenGraph(navController: NavController) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = MainScreenScreenRoutes.HomeScreen.route,
        route = ResearchHubNavigation.MainScreen.route
    ) {
        fadeThroughComposable(
            route = MainScreenScreenRoutes.HomeScreen.route,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("researchPath") {
                nullable = true
                defaultValue = null
                type = NavType.StringType
            }),
            deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = DeepLink.OpenResearch().route
                action = "android.intent.action.VIEW"
            })
        ) {
            val researchPath = it.arguments?.getString("researchPath")
            MainScreen(
                navHostController = navController,
                researchPath = researchPath
            )
        }
    }
}


DeepLink.kt
This file contains the structure for deep links, with OpenResearch configured to handle the researchPath.
sealed class DeepLink(val route: String) {
    data class OpenResearch(val researchPath: String = "{researchPath}") :
        DeepLink("$BaseDeepLinkUrl/research/${researchPath}")
}



Expected Behavior:
When a notification is tapped, the app should open to the specific research screen based on the researchPath, regardless of whether the app is open or closed.
Question:
How can I modify this setup so that the PendingIntent correctly opens the research details screen even when the app is fully closed? Any insights or suggestions for handling deep linking in a Kotlin Multiplatform environment would be greatly appreciated.

On further debugging, I noticed that the Notification service is not working properly when the app cold start
